# Jersey difference in time waiting for response first time vs. second time

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, server, jersey

I am using a Tomcat on which I have deployed a Jersey application.
On a certain REST URL it returns a fixed PNG image.
Prior to requesting the image, I have to initialize the application by providing the base path of the location of the image on the file system. This is done by performing a POST to a different URL after which the location is stored in an object in the context.

Using the network function of Firefox I can see a difference in the time the browser is waiting for the response the first time versus the second time.

[Second request waiting network time = 9 ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQnYG.png)

[Second request waiting network time = 4 ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCjv2.png)

I have executed this experiment several times and the first time always seems to take several milliseconds longer than the second or third time.

What is causing this difference?

FYI:

- header Cache-control = "no-cache"

Comment: To what these 2 times refer to exactly, retrieving the image (2 times) or setting the image URL and then retrieving the image?

Comment: both calls happen after setting on the application, the location where the image is located, so both timings you see are waiting for image retrieval.

Comment: Is your REST method hit the second time you try to retrieve the image? If not, it's possible that Tomcat returned a cached resource. Note that setting cache control in the browser has nothing to do with server-side caching (I'm only guessing here).

Comment: I also tried it with another image, by changing the image on the file system. Even with this new image (which cannot be cached yet then I assume), the new waiting times are lower than the initial waiting time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed your jersery Container as servlet . Than for each Resource 
a separate servlet is created to which the request is delegated . So first time when you request for the resource with url . The servlet has to be created . Second time the already existing servlet is used  . That is why there is response delay